# Protocols, domains and port must match error on reload

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I opened a vf page through the custom button on the object record. When user close this page I reload the parent window through javascript in the custom buttom, at this time I am getting a alert box saying this error.

Can anyone help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Already has an answer http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17639/iframe-protocols-domains-and-ports-must-match-error/17673#17673

Comment: Thanks reddev but I am not using Iframe but in the url of child window (that I open on the click of button) contains the package namespace. it can be the issue??

Comment: Yes it can be issue: `na1.force.com` != `namespace.na1.force.com` both are different. Browser won't allow it.

Comment: so do you have any solution for this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that yo are using somethig like `opener.location.reload()`. Instead of this try to redirect the opener page to the same address:

**Popup page:**

```
<script>
    window.onunload=function(){
        opener.location.href = '/{!$CurrentPage.parameters.openerId}';
    };
</script>
```

Of course you need to notice the opener page ID in the popup URL. For that just insert that ID to the Custom Button code that opens a popup, somethid like this:

**Custom button code:**

```
newPopup = window.open("/apex/PopupPage?openerId={!Object__c.Id}", "myPopup", 
                       "width=300,height=200");
newPopup.focus();
```

Comment: Thanks @mast0r actually I have created a package in my org and as per my understanding this issue is beacuse when i open the vf page on click of button, it contains the namespace in the url but not in the record url and because domain is different this is showing error.. Please guide me on this..

Comment: Well, i've tried my example with opener URL `na9.salesforce.com` and a popup URL `c.na9.visual.force.com`. And it works fine. Just try it.

Comment: I am doing like this var url="/apex/pagename?id="+"{!Account.Id}"; 
var val = window.showModalDialog(url,false,'dialogHeight:480px;');

Comment: @Mahi Try to use `window.open` method.