# Click to Dial from Visualforce Page Within Page Layout

Tags: visualforce, cti

We are experiencing this error where I cannot get click to dial functionality from a visualforce page that I have developed.

In order to troubleshoot this issue I created a simple test visualforce page and was able to determine that the click to dial functionality does in fact work when viewing the page itself, but not when the page is embedded within another record's page layout.

Here is the code for the test page:

```
<apex:page > 
<p>
<a href="javascript:sendCTIMessage('/CLICK_TO_DIAL?DN=6126713131&ID={\'003U000000jssOu\'}&ENTITY_NAME=Contact&OBJECT_NAME=MyContact');">Click This Number To Dial: {!HTMLENCODE("6126713131")}</a>
</p>
</apex:page>
```

I have also tried including the following scripts:

```
<apex:includeScript value="/support/console/28.0/integration.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="/support/api/28.0/interaction.js"/>
```

but neither (or both) of their inclusion allows click to dial functionality from when the VF page is embedded in another page's layout.

I believe this may be a similar situation as outlined in a comment on this question:

[How to USE sendCTIMessage in a visualforce page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18427/how-to-use-sendctimessage-in-a-visualforce-page)

Any/All help would be appreciated

Comment: Your issue here is the same as the question which you linked. Does the [accepted answer](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/18496/660), when used in your VF page not work embedded in the standard layout?

Comment: i have already tried that as well...

Comment: Your VF page in the question doesn't resemble what's shown in the linked question at all. At this point, any suggestions are going to be total guesses unless you can post more detail so that your issue can be reproduced by someone interested in helping.

Comment: The information in the solution instructs the developer to import the interaction javascript library, which I clearly mention that I did. Besides that, there really are no differences in the page at all....

Comment: have you tried adding the `showheader=true` attribute on your `apex:page` TAG?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to wrap phone number field in `<support:clickToDial>` tag. Please refer below link,
https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_support_clickToDial.htm

Comment: I have already tried that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Making two changes to this example worked for me:

Firstly, I used more recent versions of the two javascript includes

```
<apex:includeScript value="/support/console/38.0/integration.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="/support/api/38.0/interaction.js"/>
```

Second, I changed

```
<a href="javascript:sendCTIMessage...
```

to

```
<a href="javascript:sforce.console.cti.sendCTIMessage...
```

and that did the trick.

Updated snippet of code below:

```
<apex:page > 
<p>
<a href="javascript:sforce.console.cti.sendCTIMessage('/CLICK_TO_DIAL?DN=6126713131&ID={\'003U000000jssOu\'}&ENTITY_NAME=Contact&OBJECT_NAME=MyContact');">Click This Number To Dial: {!HTMLENCODE("6126713131")}</a>
</p>
</apex:page>
```

p.s: nearly 2 year old question, still updating the answer as I couldn't find it when I was searching for a solution for the same problem

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this problem is to use the html custom protocol extension for phone calls.

```
<a href="tel:0080072533333">00800 7253 3333</a>
```

To avoid errors on non mobile devices and computers without voip-software you should include a small javascript that checks if the custom protocol extension is supported by the current device by using this [javascript library](https://github.com/ismailhabib/custom-protocol-detection)