# Odd Security Error in Chrome

Tags: apex, visualforce, error, chrome

I have a VF page on my Dev org that calls out to a 3rd party to get some JSON results.  This page worked fine last night, this morning I started getting an odd error

[image]

But my page doesn't have any iFrames.  To test this further I stripped out the page and created a very simple VF page and Controller that are about as simple as I could think of

**VF**

```
<apex:page controller="Test1Controller" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!Save}"/>     
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Case" columns="1" >
            <apex:inputText label="Name" value="{!inputText}" id="myInput"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class Test1Controller {

    public String inputText         {get; set;}

    public PageReference Save() {
       return null;
    } 
}
```

This simple page is still getting the same error when I look at the console.  What's going on here?

[image]

> EDIT

Using Google Chrome (version below)

[image]

Comment: What browser are you using? Chrome?

Comment: Sorry, yes should have mentioned that.  Chrome.  Added the version to the question

Comment: Most likely its chrome causing this rather than your code. If you test with another browser the issue shouldn't appear.

Comment: Try with setting `showHeader="false"  standardStyleSheets="false"` @Dunc44

Comment: Problem is not in your code. It is from Salesforce. Reason is known to me but no solution.

Comment: Yes, it does seem to be Chrome, as it works in FF.  Its odd though as it worked last night.  So this is something that comes up time to time with Chrome??  No workarounds or solutions?

Comment: @Dunc44 Did you tried it with settings: `showHeader="false" standardStyleSheets="false"`

Comment: @reddev, yes i did, same error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a SalesForce error. Your page and controller look fine and are not doing anything unusual.

> swappedout:// is an internal implementation detail in Chrome that is
>   not supposed to be visible to end users

From: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=143155

**Next Steps**

Test out your app on another browser to verify that its a Chrome issue

There seems to be a lot of people having this issue when using Proxies or VPNs. So try looking there first.

There is also some mention of plugins causing this issue so try disabling all plugins that you are not using.

And let us know how you get on. We have a lot of users on Chrome and I would be interested in the cause of this.

Comment: VERY ODD. So I took your advice and disabled all my plugins, and restarted Chrome.  It worked, no error.  Now, I have reenabled all the same plugins, and restarted Chrome, it still works.  No errors.  Im stumped.  Very weird, but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is from Chrome browser or Salesforce. And reason are their javascript execution on the vf page which has issue with Salesforce and Chrome. In first snapshot it clearly visible that one of the javascript from Salesforce side or from browser side (browsers also have their some house keeping scripts/CSS) is trying to passing messages between unmatched url origins.

As it is not possible to pass message as because of browser security feature. A question already been asked [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17639/iframe-protocols-domains-and-ports-must-match-error/17673#17673).

One of the possible workaround can be is make the page minimal. Means set header to false, same as with style sheet  property. Also try with applying "`applyBodyTag=true`" and "`applyHtmlTag=true`".

Here this reason is caused because:

A javascript file named **"VFMetadataReceiver.js"** is trying to access in frame from unmatched protocol **"swappedout://"**. It is unexpected and I believe it is not related to salesforce as i found this issue with Chrome browser on google code here https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=17325.